# Tweetbot marks some tweets with a blue corner

Tags: ios, tweetbot

Some tweets in my twitterfeed is marked with a blue upper right corner, and some kind of bookmark icon on it.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [Tweet Marker](http://tweetmarker.net/) feature.

it indicates your last read tweet.  When using another app that uses Tweet Marker, it will automatically scroll to that tweet so you know where you were.

Comment: Wow, a 'would love to have'-feature that I didn't realize that I already had. Thanks :-)